# PostgreSQL => ALTER TABLE without timezone -> with timezone, using select for TZ

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I'm trying to convert the column, and preserve the data in the specified timezone. I have a script, but it errors out on the `SELECT` at the end.

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table 
ALTER COLUMN column_date TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
USING column_date AT TIME ZONE (SELECT value FROM schema.table WHERE id = 'timezone');

ERROR:  cannot use subquery in transform expression
```

I have time zones stored, but trying to pull that back to apply to the script is posing a challenge. I know I can simply hardcode the timezone as 'EST|CST|PST', etc. but I have multiple databases this needs to be applied to (with multiple alters per DB), hence the required `SELECT` at the end. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I've poured over a few questions on this subject; while some came close, they don't quite meet the needs (My apologies if this is a duplicate, I've spent a while searching for an answer).

**[RESOLVED]: Using 2 separate queries**

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table 
ALTER COLUMN column_date TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;

UPDATE schema.table 
SET column_date = column_date AT TIME ZONE 
    (SELECT value FROM schema.table WHERE id = 'timezone');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE ... AT TIME ZONE %L',
                  (SELECT value FROM atable ...));
END;$$;
```

Comment: I do like the approach, unfortunately this doesn't work for me:
ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$BEGIN.
Is this for Postgres?

Comment: I messed up, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: That works nicely, thank you. However is there a way to accomplish this without the BEGIN/END? As I need to run multiple of these in one go via a migrate script, and as per spec, I can't use BEGIN/END/DECLARE/etc...

Comment: That is not the `BEGIN` and `END` of a transaction, but a PL/pgSQL block. The whole thing is an SQL statement, and it will run in the same transaction as the surrounding code.

Comment: Understood, the command is stored in one database, and run against others however. As a result we're not able to use them. As soon as I have enough rep, I'll return to upvote your answer tho, I did find it helpful, and I do appreciate your help.

Comment: You can only access your current database unless you use `dblink`. Why don't you write a `psql` script that contains `\connect db` commands?